# How to remove \n from a mysql variable

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql variable.

```
SET @theSQL = 'CREATE VIEW `Reports` AS  
SELECT DISTINCT 
id from mytable;'
```

On inspecting the variable it has the following value,

```
'CREATE VIEW `Reports` AS\n    SELECT DISTINCT\n
```

Is there a way to remove the ***\n*** without having to do it manually?

Comment: You should still be able to execute the statement.

Comment: I am not able to execute the statement. I assumed it was because of that.

Comment: You can use `CONCAT` function!

Comment: @Bisoux . . . https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5276d5ee8d9bc4b25b0b66d739e394a4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the REPALCE function

```
REPLACE(@theSQL, '\n', '')
```

Comment: 1) This replacing may give synthactically errorneous SQL. 2) Do not use dquotes for string literals - this will not work when ANSI_QUOTES SQL mode is set..

Answer (score 0):

Replace will do the trick. Always replace with a space when you're handling strings containing SQL statements: removing whitespace can trash the statement.  On my rig I have to cope with both `\r` and `\n` so I use this.

```
SET @theSQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@theSQL , '\n', ' '), '\r', ' ');
```

But, Gordon is right. You can give MySQL's `PREPARE` a text string containing returns and newlines and it will work just fine.